# How to get the primitive value of a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: Okay, I had to redo the example because the problem didn't occur in my first example

```
function CheckboxClick(checkbox, check) {
    this.checked = check;

    checkbox.click(function (event) {
        alert(this.checked);
    });
}


CheckboxClick($("#checkbox"), $("#checkbox").attr("checked"));
```

Every time you click on that checkbox, this.checked's value changes. What do I need to do to get it to stop changing? It's obviously assigning by reference but I don't know how to get the primitive value. I tried valueOf() but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Your very end of your function is missing a `);`.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice. Yeah, I wrote it on the fly. The issue I'm having is with a more complicated function that would just clutter up what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm guessing the ) was a copy error. Once added I ran it with both prop and attr and they worked as expected (bool did not change): http://jsfiddle.net/WPsEx/3/

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I had to redo the example closer to what I originally had to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed this.checked to var checked and it works.

Note: If you're using jQuery 1.6 and above, you'll also have to change .attr method to .prop, with the same parameters.

Answer (score 2):

By primitive I think you mean the value in the html source.

Use jquery 1.6, it has a new `prop()` method and changed the meaning of `attr()` to return what is the value of the attribute in the html source.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh the issue is that `this` isn't what you maybe expecting. `this` actually refers to the checkbox that triggered the event (DOM element not jquery). So when you use `this.checked` that is the equivalent of the jquery statment `$("#checkbox").attr("checked")` which is why it changed when you clicked.

Comment: Doesn't this always alert 'undefined'?